# All subrings of $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $p$ is prime, what are all the subrings of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$? I am thinking that $\mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}_3,\ldots,\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ are all subrings of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but I am not convinced since the question goes out of it's way to specify that $p$ is a prime. What could a prime change so that some of those candidates are disqualified?

Comment: Is $\Bbb{Z}_{p-1}$ A) a subset of $\Bbb{Z}_p$, B) does it have the same operations? Hint: The correct answers are A) No, B) No, or more precisely, it cannot have, because it is not a subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ (integers modulo $p$) by $\Bbb Z_p$ (as opposed to the $p$-adic integers).

**Hint:** The underlying additive group $(S,+)$ of a subring $S$ of a ring $R$ must be a subgroup of the underlying additive group $(R,+)$ of $R$. What are the possible subgroups of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z,+)$?

Comment: The answer I got in class from the professor is $(\mathbb{Z}_p,+,\times)$. But I don't understand why that is. And yes, the notation used does mean integers modulo $p$.

Comment: Oh yes, the only subgroups are $0$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ itself.

Comment: Then the only possible subrings are ______ (fill in the blank). Are they both subrings? (Check your definition of subring and see if they fit.)

Comment: It must be a proper subset of the ring, so only $\{0\}$ would be the subring.

Comment: I've never heard of the convention that a subring must be a proper subset, and if that's one of your assumptions, your professor's answer was wrong. However, sometimes it is required that a subring have a unit element and moreover, that the unit element $1$ in the subring agrees with the unit element of the original ring. You should make sure you know what conventions you're using.

Comment: I think I misread the textbook, this is the definition I am using http://imgur.com/a/0GwAK . I saw the proper subset symbol and that is what I thought. Using this definition, both are subrings.